Using google generativeai in JS with in-memory images
Im trying to use @google/generative-ai in Javascript with in-memory images. My server gets the images from Http Requests. In google documentation it shows that:
// TODO Make these files available on the local file system
// You may need to update the file paths
const files = [
    await uploadToGemini("file_path", "image/jpeg"),
];

async function uploadToGemini(path, mimeType) {
  const uploadResult = await fileManager.uploadFile(path, {
    mimeType,
    displayName: path,
  });
  const file = uploadResult.file;
  console.log(`Uploaded file ${file.displayName} as: ${file.name}`);
  return file;
}

const fileManager = new GoogleAIFileManager(apiKey);

So it expects a file path. So now I need to

Save the image to a local folder
Read the image from local folder and upload it to google servers
Delete the image from local folder

It seems unnecessary. The image is being sent in base64 format anyway, why should I save it to the local file instead of directly sending the image from memory. As far as documentation goes, I couldn't find a way to achieve that. Is there a workaround for this?
I looked at the source code of GoogleAIFileManager it only accepts filePath as parameter.

I get the impression that you begin to have a xy-problem. Of course: The file manager expects that you work with files. However, even the NPM page shows a small example that works with a base64 string - it only adds the additional step of Buffer.from(fs.readFileSync("cookie.png")).toString("base64") which you should be able to skip if you already have the file in base64.

@Davi Yeah i can't believe i missed that. Thank you for your answer that worked.
